# python/cython compiling pyx: fatal error: capsule.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, c++, cython, pyx

I recently worked on a python project where I need to import some `.pyx` files.

However, I had a hard time import it as `.pyx` and compile it with the following lines:

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
from . import kl
```

The error is

```
fatal error: capsule.h: No such file or directory
```

And in the `kl.pyx` file, `capsule.h` is used as following:

```
cdef extern from "capsule.h":
     void* Capsule_AsVoidPtr(object ptr)
```

I am not sure what I should do. Please help me a little bit.

**Alternatively**, is it possible that the python script could import compiled `.c` (in Linux) file directly, instead of importing `.pyx` and compile it? 
When I compile it with command line, it is compiled successfully, but I don't know how my IDE (PyCharm) could import that `.c` file.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed some library, you need to install the source code of capsule.h.